# Microsoft.Office.Interop restrict the paragraph modification

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop, word-interop

I am trying to protect the paragraph from modification.i am generating the Doc file using Office interop word library I want to put a restriction or password protection on few paragraphs in the docx no one can modify that but other paragraphs they can modify

```
    var app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

    app.Visible = true;

    Document document = app.Documents.Open(@"C:\Test\NewDocument.docx")          

    String read = string.Empty;
    List<string> data = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < document.Paragraphs.Count; i++)
    {
        string temp = document.Paragraphs[i + 1].Range.Text.Trim();
        if (temp != string.Empty)
            data.Add(temp);
    }
    data.Add("Next LINE");
    data.Add("Second");

    object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

    foreach (var item in data)
    {

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph para1 = document.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref missing);
        para1.Range.Text = item;
        para1.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();


    }

    document.Save();
    document.Close();
    return null;
```

Comment: First step:familiarze yourself with the available options in Developer/Restrict Editing, you should find what you're looking for there. Then record setting the option that works for you in a macro to get the basic syntax. Transfer this logic to C#. If you run into a problem with it at that point, ask back...

Comment: I read this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-programmatically-protect-documents-and-parts-of-documents?view=vs-2019

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56294094/c-sharp-microsoft-office-interop-word-protect-the-paragraph

Answer (score 0):

Its working just format issue

```
public string ExtractText()
        {


            var app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();


            Document document = app.Documents.Open(@"C:\Test\656.docx");


            String read = string.Empty;
            List<string> data = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < document.Paragraphs.Count; i++)
            {
                string temp = document.Paragraphs[i + 1].Range.Text.Trim();
                if (temp != string.Empty)
                    data.Add(temp);
            }
            data.Add("Next LINE");
            data.Add("Second method opens the existing Microsoft Office Word document specified by a fully qualified path and file name. This method returns a Document that represents the opened document");
            data.Add("Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney C");

            object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

           app.ActiveDocument.Content.Editors.Add(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdEditorType.wdEditorEveryone);


            foreach (var item in data)
            {

             var para = document.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref missing);
              para.Range.Text = item.Trim();
              para.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();


                if (para.Range.Text.Contains("Second"))
                {

                     para = document.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref missing);
                    para.Range.Editors.Add(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdEditorType.wdEditorEditors).Delete();
                }

                if (para.Range.Text.Contains("Contrary"))
                {

                    para = document.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref missing);
                    //   var para1 = document.Content.Paragraphs[1].Range.Paragraphs.Add(ref missing);
                    para.Range.Editors.Add(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdEditorType.wdEditorEveryone).Delete();
                }
                else
                {

                    para = document.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref missing);

                    para.Range.Editors.Add(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdEditorType.wdEditorEveryone);
                }


            }

            app.Visible = true;

            object noReset = true;
            object password = System.String.Empty;
            object useIRM = false;
            object enforceStyleLock = true;

            object PasswordEncryptionFileProperties = false;
            app.ActiveDocument.EnforceStyle = true;

            document.Protect(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdProtectionType.wdAllowOnlyReading, ref noReset, "000", ref useIRM, ref enforceStyleLock);

            document.Save();
            document.Close();
```