# C# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word protect the paragraph

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I'm using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word with C#. I know that you can set modification restricted for a specific paragraph.

**Example**

- Paragraph1 you **can’t** modify
- Paragraph2 you **can** edit
- Paragraph3 you **can’t** modify

The issue I am having in the code is it is protecting the first paragraph, but after that users are able to modify the other paragraph, please check the codes Thanks

```
public string ExtractText()
    {


        var app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();


        Document document = app.Documents.Open(@"C:\Test\656.docx");


        String read = string.Empty;
        List<string> data = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < document.Paragraphs.Count; i++)
        {
            string temp = document.Paragraphs[i + 1].Range.Text.Trim();
            if (temp != string.Empty)
                data.Add(temp);
        }
        data.Add("Next LINE");
        data.Add("Second method opens the existing Microsoft Office Word document specified by a fully qualified path and file name. This method returns a Document that represents the opened document");
        data.Add("Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney C");

        object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

       app.ActiveDocument.Content.Editors.Add(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdEditorType.wdEditorEveryone);


        foreach (var item in data)
        {

         var para = document.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref missing);
          para.Range.Text = item.Trim();
          para.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();


            if (para.Range.Text.Contains("Second"))
            {

                 para = document.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref missing);
                para.Range.Editors.Add(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdEditorType.wdEditorEditors).Delete();
            }

            if (para.Range.Text.Contains("Contrary"))
            {

                para = document.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref missing);
                //   var para1 = document.Content.Paragraphs[1].Range.Paragraphs.Add(ref missing);
                para.Range.Editors.Add(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdEditorType.wdEditorEveryone).Delete();
            }
            else
            {

                para = document.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref missing);

                para.Range.Editors.Add(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdEditorType.wdEditorEveryone);
            }


        }

        app.Visible = true;

        object noReset = true;
        object password = System.String.Empty;
        object useIRM = false;
        object enforceStyleLock = true;

        object PasswordEncryptionFileProperties = false;
        app.ActiveDocument.EnforceStyle = true;

        document.Protect(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdProtectionType.wdAllowOnlyReading, ref noReset, "000", ref useIRM, ref enforceStyleLock);

        document.Save();
        document.Close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public string ExtractText()
    {

        var app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();


        Document document = app.Documents.Open(@"C:\Test\90.docx");


    //    app.ActiveDocument.Protect.p

        String read = string.Empty;
        List<string> data = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < document.Paragraphs.Count; i++)
        {
            string temp = document.Paragraphs[i + 1].Range.Text.Trim();
            if (temp != string.Empty)
                data.Add(temp);
        }
        data.Add("Next LINE");
        data.Add("Next LINE");
        data.Add("Second method opens the existing Microsoft Office Word document specified by a fully qualified path and file name. This method returns a Document that represents the opened document");
        data.Add("Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney C");

        object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

   app.ActiveDocument.Content.Editors.Add(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdEditorType.wdEditorEveryone);


        foreach (var item in data)
        {

         var para = document.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref missing);
          para.Range.Text = item.Trim();
          para.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();






     app.Visible = true;

        object noReset = true;
        object password = System.String.Empty;
        object useIRM = false;
        object enforceStyleLock = true;

        object PasswordEncryptionFileProperties = false;
        app.ActiveDocument.EnforceStyle = true;

        document.Protect(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdProtectionType.wdAllowOnlyReading, ref noReset, "000", ref useIRM, ref enforceStyleLock);
        document.Paragraphs[1].Range.Editors.Add(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdEditorType.wdEditorEditors);
        document.Paragraphs[2 + 1].Range.Editors.Add(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdEditorType.wdEditorEveryone);
        document.Paragraphs[1 + 1].Range.Editors.Add(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdEditorType.wdEditorEditors);




        document.Save();
        document.Close();}
```